# Waterproof wax on my arm while doing wudu

Tags: hadith, salat, women, dua, wudu

If someone could please help to clear this doubt it will help a lot. So before I started doing my wudu I was aware of the fact that there was wax on my arm. After I had finished praying and made my dua after some minutes I seen the wax on my arm and I realised that my wudu has in this case been invalid all this time. I have read on Islamic websites that if water doesn’t follow over all the required parts when doing wudu, the wudu is invalidated. But I also read that if u saw it after ur prayer u don’t have to repeat ur prayers, yes I saw it after my prayers but I knew about it before doing my wudu but it had slipped my mind to take the wax off. So My question is that do I need to repeat my prayers the ones I read with that same wudu or not?

Answer (score 0):

See it is  the fact depending that whether you really forgot so I think you should remove it  and then  you once again after removing it pray again because  if water dose not make contact to skin it invalidates the wudu .so i think you should pray again .as wudu is important for prayer itself .                                                                             1 hope it helps                                                                                                         thank you

Comment: Thankyouuu & yeah I removed the wax and prayed again as I didn’t feel satisfied with my prayer.